# Isotope Sorting

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

I have a jsfiddle set up with the isotope plugin, and I am trying to add the sorting functionality, so that when you click on the sorting links, the elements that have that class are brought to the top, but the others are not hidden.

Does anybody know how to add the sorting code to this?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Skn2S/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var classes = ["width2", "height2", "width2height2", ];
    var $container = $('#container');

    // add randomish size classes
    $container.find('.element').each(function () {
        $(this).addClass(classes[~~ (Math.random() * classes.length)]);
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    var $container = $('#container');

    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.element',
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: 120
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these [Isotope Sorting Docs](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/sorting.html)

You could do something like this (unverified)

```
<div class="element car" data-category="ferarri">
```

and in your code

```
...
getSortData : {
  category : function ( $elem ) {
    //Returns 1 for when it matches, 0 otherwise
    return $elem.attr('data-category')==($('#sorts .selected').html());
  }
}

$('#sorts  a').click(function(){
  var sortName = $(this).html(); //e.g. 'Ferarri'
  $('#container').isotope({ sortBy : 'category'});
  return false;
});
```

Some other notes

- No need to (i.e. shouldn't) add 'isotope-item' class to each element in your HTML markup. In some more complex scenarios (lazy loading etc.), it'll cause problems.
- I don't *think* your nested divs will work inside a single isotope-container. (I could be wrong) - I'm not sure you'll even need them after applying the above.